CallStack of chain of methods
I'm trying to find out a way to get the complete method chain call stack A() -> B() -> C() -> D(). However, StackWalker or Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() returns only the originating method and the method in which stacktrace is logged, it skips branch calls main() -> A() -> D()
Stacktrace:
com.sample.TestClass.D(TestClass.java:21)
com.sample.TestClass.A(TestClass.java:9)
com.sample.TestClass.main(TestClass.java:28)

Class
package com.sample;

import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class TestClass {

    public void A() {
        B();
        D();
    }

    public void B() {
        C();
    }

    public void C() {
    }

    public void D() {
        System.out.println(StackWalker.getInstance()
                .walk(s -> s.filter(f -> f.getClassName().startsWith("com.sample")).collect(Collectors.toList())).stream()
                .map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestClass t = new TestClass();
        t.A();
    }
}



B and C are not in the call stack.

yes, i understand that. I'm trying to figure out how can i get it in my call stack. Current approach will not give but if there is any other way to achieve this ?

well, if you call D() from C() that would do it, right?

I'm a little confused about what the question/problem is here.

Goal is to find out the method calls like com.sample.TestClass.D(TestClass.java:22) com.sample.TestClass.C(TestClass.java:17) com.sample.TestClass.B(TestClass.java:13) com.sample.TestClass.A(TestClass.java:8) I'm not saying java isn't doing correct. Also, I don't have option to call D() from C()

"if there is any other way to achieve this" No.  There is no way to get what you want.

Alternately, instrumenting the code with something like a code coverage tool would log each method called (plus lots of other possibly extraneous information).

Java is correct here.  B and C are done executing by the time you call D, so they don't belong in the call stack.
There is no way to get B and C from the body of D.

You have TWO possible (separate) paths:
A -> B -> C
A -> D

The following path is NOT part of your code. This chain will never happen. You'll never have a call from C to D (etc).
A -> B -> C -> D

You may be looking for a SOURCE CODE analysis tool, which would show you the flow of all calls. Something like this:
A -> (B -> C) | (D)

But you have to take into account that some chains are more complicated and impossible to serialize in this way. For instance, suppose you have a recursive call from A to A (maybe indirectly: A -> B -> A). Now add the (very common) use of conditional calls (ie. an if before some call).
Another option, as already been said, is some kind of EXECUTION (run-time) log/trace, which would give you something like:
A called B
    called C
      returned-to B
    returned-to A
  called D
    returned-to A

But again: when using a loop, this would log several lines for each repeated call from (for instance) B to C; and when using conditionals, it would just show the specific path taken by your code under specific conditions.
